# Does anyone know anybody from Ratio Christi?

Tags: discussion

I had never heard of this [organization](http://ratiochristi.org/) until today, but

- they sound like people I'd like to know
- they sound like people that could really help fill this site with good material

Yes, I'm a little bit obsessed with driving traffic to my addiction, excuse me, this site. Still, if we knew anybody, I'd love to get people to come.

Comment: Apparently [they have no manners](http://freethoughtblogs.com/butterfliesandwheels/2012/02/christians-got-no-manners/).